# Can I use a .NET attribute without depending on the assembly that defines it?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-management

I am unclear about the rules regarding attributes and assembly dependencies.

Is it possible (and not a terrible idea) to annotate the types in an assembly with custom attributes from a NuGet package *without* introducing a run-time dependency on that NuGet package?  Could clients use the types in the assembly without also needing to have the custom package's assemblies present?

I ask because My .NET application uses two packages:

1. A third party NuGet package called **[YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet)** for serializing types to YAML.  It lets you control YAML serialization with custom attributes analogous to Microsoft's XML attributes (e.g. it has `YamlIgnoreAttribute` like MS' `XmlIgnoreAttribute`)
2. My own package, **PackageA** which does *not* depend upon YamlDotNet.

I want my app to serialize my types from PackageA using YamlDotNet.  But they will not serialize correctly unless I do one of the following:

1. annotate the types in PackageA with YamlDotNet custom attributes
2. create annotated wrappers for PackageA types in the App to do the serialization for me.

I can do #2, but it would be easier to do #1.   But I do not want to introduce a run-time dependency on YamlDotNet for all clients of PackageA.  *Ideally, I would like anybody using PackageA who also happens to be using YamlDotNet to get those attibutes for free and for them to be invisible to anyone else.*

Is what I want possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are a compile-time feature, you will always need reference to YamlDotNet in order to use one of its types as compile-time type metadata, unless you are open to doing things like generating your model classes in run-time (which is quite probably way more troublesome than having a one extra package reference).

This is a general problem where using attribute-driven features of a serializer pollutes the target assembly and couples it with that serializer.

There are three ways to address this:

1. Accept this as a compromise
2. Move YamlDotNet-specific into a separate assembly
3. Have a separate serialization model

The first point should be quite clear - this is what you don't want and your first ssuggestion.

The second point could be creating YamlDotNet-specific type wrappers or type converters (if it supports such things) in a separate assembly so that the core assembly stays clean. This is your second suggestion, just with a twist of converters that may be more pleasant than wrapping everything from consumer perspective.

The third point is about creating DTOs/payloads in the core assembly so that you never have to use any serializer-specific attributes and the serialization just works out of the box. If you need to `[YamlIgnore]` properties, the model used for serialization probably also serves other purposes so this is basically just a separation of concerns. If you serialize your application model, you might find it impossible to provide backwards compatibility without affecting business logic at various places as a result.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I feared as much.  I've already polluted the assembly with `[XmlIgnore]` attributes and the like.  I can live with those since they are from a standard assembly, but I don't want to do it again. I think the best approach for the long term is your suggestion #3. Thank you